# Troubleshooting crash in Android System WebView

Tags: android, webview, crash, chromium, android-vitals

On Android Vitals we start receiving more and more crashes from Android System WebView(base.apk!libmonochrome.so&base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so). The crash log isn't useful:

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000003fd242c  /data/app/~~W6uLnBBDOoB9wa7BdzPO_g==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_469208734-hhrIEJFSycFvr19h-G8H4w==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (offset 0x668000)
  ...
  #00  pc 00000000000a5790  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+856)
  #00  pc 00000000000035a0  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1368)
  #00  pc 0000000000049ccc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+108)
```

Samsung users are impacted most but also Oppo, OnePlus and Xiaomi. The crash seems to appear only on Android 10 and 11. But we didn't know what exact version of WebView users have and what causes crashes. Worth mentioning that the app uses ads from Google.

What we already tried:

- Added `onRenderProcessGone` into all `WebView` used by the app.
- Used different versions of Android System WebView downloaded from APKMirror.
- Created an issue on https://issuetracker.google.com.
- Made research on Stackoverflow, Google&Chromium issue trackers, etc.

None of that didn't help to debug the problem, also no response on the Google issue tracker during a few weeks.

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot/fix this issue?

We will be grateful for any help or ideas.